# Is it possible to monitor Amazon S3 resource usage via a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

Let say, I have a web application that allows users to upload images and documents and my application stores all those assets on S3, is there a way I can monitor resource usage PER user account?

For example, if a user account has a 1GB storage limit, how can I monitor how much of that allowance any individual is using?

Furthermore (but this is less of an issue to me) if that user account also has a 5GB bandwidth limit, are there any tools available that allow me to monitor just their S3 bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You can use [papreclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to manage file uploads (or any other reputable upload management plugin/gem).  Most of these tools give you access to the filesize of the uploaded file.  You can simply store these files in the database along with the asset_uri (which I imagine you're already storing), and to check if a user can upload another file, simply sum all the sizes of all assets with the appropriate user_id.

```
Users:
  id
  email_address
  first_name
  upload_limit

Assets:
  id
  user_id
  uri
  filesize
  filename
```

Then, to grab the total size of uploaded files by a particular user, you could do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets

  #Check if the user can upload another file
  def can_upload?
    if Asset.sum('filesize', :conditions => 'user_id = #{self.id}') >= self.upload_limit
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

  #See the user's used storage space
  def used_storage
    return Asset.sum('filesize', :conditions => 'user_id = #{self.id}')
  end

  #See how much space the user has remaining
  def available_storage
    if self.can_upload?
      return self.upload_limit - Asset.sum('filesize', :conditions => 'user_id = #{self.id}')
    else
      return 0
    end
  end
end
```

You can see I'm making use of the [ActiveRecord sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002191) function here to do the calculation.  You could just as easily use a map or some other ruby based solution.